# map vs multimap in C++ (performance)

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am working on data structure where input is very large almost 1 TB. I need to load data into associative container.

Data has some duplicate entires so i am using multimap but someone suggested me to use map of vector instead of using this. May i know what is the difference performance wise?

```
 map<const char*, const char*, cmptr> mulmap;

 map <const char*, vector <const char*> ,cmptr> mmap;
```

Comment: Why don't you try them both, and find out?

Comment: Actually, in both cases your performance is likely to be dominated by disk speed, unless you have a system with 1TB of RAM...

Comment: If you want to use `const char*` as key, you must also supply a comparison predicate for this to work. It would be easier to use `std::map<std::string, std::string>` instead.

Comment: Please. I beg you. Don't use `const char*` if you mean to use it as a string. Use `std::string` instead. Just... please!

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @MarkGarcia Why you beg him? He/She has a 1TB structure and if he/she can save structure that needed for strings to just one pointer and store that string somewhere else this is awesome. In normal programming use case `std::string` is much better than `const char*` but this is not always the case. `map` and `multimap` both provide a comparer that we can use to allow `const char*` as a key and even `unordered_map` and `unordered_multimap` has a template hash function! so it work perfectly with `C++` and it may be even the only case

Comment: i need to store the content of 1 million files into map/multimap and need to apply my algo to process the data and print the output.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351153/multimap-vs-map-with-set

Comment: @user15662 Why does your algorithm require all the data to be in memory at the same time?

Comment: Unless the keys are always string literals, you'd probably be better off using `std::string`.  Otherwise, you're going to have lifetime issues.  And if you're reading the data all in one go, then processing it, you'd probably be better off using `std::vector<std::pair<char const*, char const*>>`, and sorting the vector once after reading the entire data.  `std::vector` will improve locality enormously, which will likely make a significant difference here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602068/whats-the-difference-between-stdmultimapkey-value-and-stdmapkey-stds

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are wasting your time thinking about `map` versus `multimap`.  Suppose that the number of bins is N and the average number of items per bin is M.

A `std::multimap<Key, Val>` typically uses an RB tree with duplicate keys.

- Fetch is O(log N + log M)
- Insert is O(log N + log M)
- Delete is O(log N + log M)
- Iteration is O(1)

A `std::map<Key, std::vector<Val>>` typically uses an RB tree with unique keys.

- Fetch is O(log N)
- Insert is O(log N)
- Delete is O(log N)
- Iteration is O(1)

As you can see, the difference is not worth talking about unless M is very large.

However, the storage of both is limited by RAM.  1 TB is simply not feasible for most systems, and no motherboard I've heard of supports it.

You are better off using a database for 1 TB of data.  You can choose almost any database for this task.  [Kyoto Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/) is simple and does what you want, but you can also use PostgreSQL, MySQL, Sqlite, Dynamo, Redis, MongoDB, Cassandra, Voldemort...

Comment: For "1 TB of data", one actually needs to be careful on which database and how the data is accessed .. there be restrictions and such.

Comment: @user15662: I still recommend Kyoto Cabinet over `std::` anything for this kind of job.

Comment: +1 @user15662 then having a rock-solid DB backend should be a given. I concur with Dietrich here.

Comment: For those of us with merely human levels of ram, we could expect the performance of multimap to be roughly equivalent to map with vector?

Comment: @Carbon: Depends on what you want to do with the data. In general, no. But vector is often the right choice.

Answer (score 5):

With 1 TB of input, I would use neither. Most likely, you don't have enough RAM. Use some on disk data structure like [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree).