# Efficiency of Map of Sets compared to Multimap in Memory and Lookup Time

Tags: c++, dictionary, set, multimap

I was wondering in which cases to use a multimap rather than a map of sets.

Say I have a bunch of tuples that consist of <[0-9],[0-9]+>. So, they have 0-9 on the left and 0 - unlimited on the right.

I could now make a map and have the left side of the tuples as the key. The value would be a set of the right sides of all the tuples that have the same left side. This way I would have log(10) lookup time for the left and in case of an unordered set “hash-time”  lookup time for the right side.
I don't know how multimaps work internally... so, assuming they put all right sides in a vector and then do binary search on it that would be worse that hash-tiem lookup (provided a good has function)... but I don’t know how they work. So, in cases like this, what is the better choice? What takes less time, what uses less memory?

And I know this has been asked already for example here: [multimap vs map with set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351153/multimap-vs-map-with-set)

But my question is more specific, as the left side of the tuples is very restricted in variance and also the answers in that thread contain a lot of guessing about the implementation of multimaps.

## Edit

So to go with the numbers example I could have <2, 928947>. Specifically I need this for strings though, to store a grammar for a parser, which needs to lookup rules by their left hand side.

Comment: Can you add example to your question - what you want to have in your container - just a few entries

Comment: Under the circumstances, it seems to me that you'd be better off with `std::vector<std::set<int>> s(10);` I don't see any benefit from using anything set-like given that the only keys are 0..9. You might, however, want to just create a trie of some sort.

Comment: well... I need it to be be scalable. I know the left side will always have a lower variance than the right, but the variance could be larger than 10 and not necessarily be integers.